# prevent an Instantiated prefab to be re-Instantiate if it exist 2D Game in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, prefab

Hello and thanks for reading.

I'm not very experienced with coding and stuff, I have a shield that can be activated on collision

the problem if the shield is already Instantiated, and the player picks up again the shield power-up, the shield will double, and so on.

I want a solution for my Instantiation line below, to prevent the shield to be Instantiated many times every pickup.

thank you.

```
GameObject shi = Instantiate(bubble, bubblepoz.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make "GameObject shi" a global variable by taking it out of the function.

Than do this

```
if (shi == null)
{
shi = Instantiate(bubble, bubblepoz.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
}
```

Comment: hello and thank you for your simple solution, now I have another new problem when I pick up the shield, and it disappears with a coroutine, but can't initiate it anymore when picking up the power up again.

Comment: i meant Instantiate

Comment: when it disappears with the coroutine make sure you set shi to equal null again.

Comment: work perfectly, Thank you so much, I wish you the best with all your project